# How to change top margin for centered elements in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am displaying element inside the `App_body`. The element are centered horizontally and vertically using `Flex`.

```
<div className="App-body">
< Element1 className="element1"/>
< Element2 />
< Element3 />
 </div>

.App-body {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}
```

The three element are centered in the middle of the screen. I am trying to put the fist element on the top but this is not working.

```
.element1{
top: 0;
}
```

How can I set the top margin of the first element?

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to achieve. Please explain in more detail or provide an example. Your question talks about top-margin, however your detailed description is using absolute positioning which has nothing to do with top-margin.

Comment: absolute position was just a try. I want to ignore the parent positioning and want to be able to change the top margin of element1 to stick in to the top of the page

Comment: Added a solution, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to ignore the parent positioning and want to be able to change
>   the top margin of element1 to stick in to the top of the page

You can use absolute positioning to solve your problem. You would have to position your parent container and then use absolute position to position your child element and remove it from normal flow of parent container.

```
.App-body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.element1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  justify-content: space-between;
```

Is what you want if you need to space them all out, with the first element at the top, second center and last at the bottom. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Almost. I want all the item to be in the center but not the fist one. Is it not possible to ignore the parent positioning and be able to set the element1 top to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Add this style to element1 class

```
.element1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flex items can have their `margin: auto` for dividing available space between them. e.g.:

```css
.App-body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: stretch;
  height: 100vh;
}

.App-body > *:first-child,
.App-body > *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}

.App-body > * {
  height: 20px;
  width: 50%;
  background: orange;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="App-body">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```